# Is there a way to block meta refresh from auto refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, html, userscripts

I go to a website page that has the code below that after one minute redirects me to another page.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60; URL='LinkToAnotherWebsite.com'">
```

I was looking for a way to disable the meta refresh only on this website (by using user scripts) or some solution that does not block the manual page refresh or redirection (like then you click a link). While I was able to do what I wanted with the code below in a user script, it also completely broke the website, its search did not worked nor did the F5.

```
window.setInterval(function () {window.stop()},10)
```

Comment: Remove the `<meta>` tag from the document?

Comment: @Phil yeah that's a solution, or it would be if I was the admin. I think it should be possible to do with user scripts but I don't know how, that's why I'm asking

Answer (score -1):

you can always override the value of the meta tag using javascirpt

```
Array
    .from(document.getElementsByTagName("meta"))
    .filter(elem => elem.getAttributeNames().includes("http-equiv") && elem.getAttribute("http-equiv") === "refresh")[0] // it might return undefined so put it in try catch
    .setAttribute("content", "VALUE YOU WANT TO SET");
```

Comment: But how can I auto embed it on the page? Can I use user script to do it?

Comment: if you control that site than you can directly remove it from the code and if you dont have control on that site than you can configure refresh settings in your browser to neglect refresh else you can also use extension or create one